# jq print character inside output

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

I want print `"/"` separator inside output title.

```
curl  -s http://cd0a4a.ethosdistro.com/?json=yes \
    | jq -c '.rigs|."0d6b27",."50dc35"|[.version,.driver,.miner,"\(.gpus)\(.miner_instance)"]|@csv' \
    | sed 's/\\//g;s/\"//g' \
    | gawk 'BEGIN{print  "version" "," "GPU_driver" "," "miner" "," "gpu"} {print $0}' \
    | csvlook -I
```

---

The output is like this :

```
| version | GPU_driver | miner    | gpu |
| ------- | ---------- | -------- | --- |
| 1.2.3   | nvidia     | ethminer | 22  |
| 1.2.4   | amdgpu     | ethminer | 11  |
```

---

But I want separator in between the numbers inside gpu title like this :

```
| version | GPU_driver | miner    | gpu  |
| ------- | ---------- | -------- | ---- |
| 1.2.3   | nvidia     | ethminer | 2/2  |
| 1.2.4   | amdgpu     | ethminer | 1/1  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing a lot of unnecessary calls just to process the data. Your commands could be drastically simplified.

- You don't need to explicitly key into the `.rigs` object to get their values, you could just access them using `[]`.
- You don't need the sed call to strip the quotes, just use the raw output `-r`.
- You don't need the awk call to add the header, you could just output an additional row from jq.

So your command turns into this instead:

```
$ curl -s http://cd0a4a.ethosdistro.com/?json=yes \
| jq -r '["version", "GPU_driver", "miner", "gpu"],
         (.rigs[] | [.version, .driver, .miner, "\(.gpus)/\(.miner_instance)"])
             | @csv' \
| csvlook -I
```

Comment: so so so thanks my people but i want ask another quistion about same thing

Answer (score 1):

Since you already use [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo)) for that specific field, simply include the character you need (slash `/`) inside the string, like this:

```
curl ... | jq -c '... [.version,.driver,.miner,"\(.gpus)/\(.miner_instance)"] ...'
```

In your case (the complete line):

```
curl -s http://cd0a4a.ethosdistro.com/?json=yes | jq -c '.rigs|."0d6b27",."50dc35"|[.version,.driver,.miner,"\(.gpus)/\(.miner_instance)"]|@csv' | sed 's/\\//g;s/\"//g' | gawk 'BEGIN{print  "version" "," "GPU_driver" "," "miner" "," "gpu"} {print $0}' | csvlook -I
```

Comment: really thanks people i really appreciate  this really really thanks

Comment: no i completely accept its so useful i just am new here so maybe i did some wrong so i did not vote against it so so thanks my friend

Comment: I see you're new on StackOverflow, so let me wish you a welcome! :) See here [how accepting of an answer works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). (You should check the green checkmark, that marks the question as answered.)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions for simplification:

- use the `--raw-output` option to `jq` to remove extraneous back-slashes
- there is no need to remove the quotes, `csvlook` does it for you
- no need for awk to add a title line, use a sub-shell
- no need to specify rigs implicitly, use `.[]`

Here is an example:

```
(
  echo version,GPU_driver,miner,gpu
  curl -s 'http://cd0a4a.ethosdistro.com/?json=yes' |
  jq -r '
    .rigs | .[] |
    [ .version, .driver , .miner  , "\(.gpus)/\(.miner_instance)" ] |
    @csv
  '
) |
csvlook
```

Output:

```
|----------+------------+----------+------|
|  version | GPU_driver | miner    | gpu  |
|----------+------------+----------+------|
|  1.2.3   | nvidia     | ethminer | 2/2  |
|  1.2.4   | amdgpu     | ethminer | 1/1  |
|----------+------------+----------+------|
```

Comment: thank you my friend iv been try it it works very well