# jq name of title as new column on table

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

hi my people i have problem i use jq command line so i want print the name of array on one title with table so this is it :

```
curl  -s http://cd0a4a.ethosdistro.com/?json=yes  | jq '.rigs'
```

this is the main work link :

```
curl  -s http://cd0a4a.ethosdistro.com/?json=yes |jq -c '.rigs|."0d6b27",."50dc35"|[.version,.driver,.miner,"\(.gpus)/\(.miner_instance)"]|@    csv'|sed 's/\\//g;s/\"//g' |  gawk 'BEGIN{print  "version" "," "GPU_driver" "," "miner" "," "gpu"} {print $0}' | csvlook -I
```

the result it :

```
| version | GPU_driver | miner    | gpu  |
| ------- | ---------- | -------- | ---- |
| 1.2.3   | nvidia     | ethminer | 2/2  |
| 1.2.4   | amdgpu     | ethminer | 1/1  |
```

but i need it to be like this :

```
| version | GPU_driver | miner    | gpu  |  rigname  |
| ------- | ---------- | -------- | ---- |-----------|
| 1.2.3   | nvidia     | ethminer | 2/2  |  0d6b27   |
| 1.2.4   | amdgpu     | ethminer | 1/1  |  50dc35   |
```

Comment: I don't think this a duplicate.  Here is a solution.  What you need to do is capture the key of the `.rigs` object.  This is easily done with [variable binding](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Variable/SymbolicBindingOperator:...as$identifier|...) and [keys](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#keys,keys_unsorted) as follows `.rigs|keys[] as $name|.[$name]|[.version,.driver,.miner,"\(.gpus)/\(.miner_instance)",$name]`.  See  [https://jqplay.org/s/WR7fEjTQJ4](https://jqplay.org/s/WR7fEjTQJ4)

Comment: thanks man i really appreciate this but i did not understand what you mean exactly so this is the link gave it to me after change please                                                           curl  -s http://cd0a4a.ethosdistro.com/?json=yes |jq -c '.rigs|."0d6b27",."50dc35"|[.version,.driver,.miner,"\(.gpus)/\(.miner_instance)"]|@    csv'|sed 's/\\//g;s/\"//g' |  gawk 'BEGIN{print  "version" "," "GPU_driver" "," "miner" "," "gpu"} {print $0}' | csvlook -I

Comment: [main] curl  -s http://cd0a4a.ethosdistro.com/?json=yes |jq -c '.rigs | "50dc35" as $50dc35 |."0d6b27",."50dc35"|[.version,.driver,.miner,"\(.gpus)/\(.miner_instance)",.$50dc35 ]|@csv'|sed 's/\\//g;s/\"//g' |  gawk 'BEGIN{print  "version" "," "GPU_driver" "," "miner" "," "gpu"} {print $0}' | csvlook -I
 is it like this ? i did it and fail

Comment: The main thing I wanted to point out is that with `keys` you can stop hardcoding the 0x6b27 etc.  First do `curl  -s 'http://cd0a4a.ethosdistro.com/?json=yes' | jq -c '.rigs|keys[] as $name|.[$name]|[.version,.driver,.miner,"\(.gpus)/\(.miner_i‌​nstance)",$name]'` . Once that part looks right to you try adding more although [as others have pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46432449) you probably don't need as much as you have in there.  Small moves, Ellie. Small moves.

Comment: thank you so so much my friend really really thanks